# LINQ "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error

Tags: c#, linq, oracle11g

The below LINQ statement doesn't like my `.ToList()` method. I've used this in other LINQ statements, but not with group by's. After removing the `.ToList()` method the code works great in LINQPad.  So does anyone know why I would be getting the above Oracle error? I'm getting this error using C#.  Oracle 11g.

```
var result = (from d in db.SLSPERDTs
              group d by new { d.YR, d.PERNUM } into g
              select g.First()).ToList();
```

From this Oracle table, I'm simply trying to group by the `YR` & `PERNUM` columns and I only want the FIRST row from each group.

Comment: are you using the same database driver from linqpad and code?

Comment: Try with `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`.

Comment: That didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because you are selecting `g.First()` and that will always be one object or null (i think).  Try this:

```
var result = (from d in db.SLSPERDTs
      group d by new { d.YR, d.PERNUM } into g
      select g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: But how would removing the First() method get me the results I'm looking for?  I've got this table with a bunch of Years & Periods, but different Week Numbers, so I'm trying to group the Years & Periods together and JUST grab the first one only for each group.

Comment: Try it with `g.FirstOrDefault()` see my edit.  That could give you that functionality and still let you do the tolist maybe..

Answer (score 0):

After some research on the web, here is my refined LINQPad code that works just fine using C# Statement(s):

```
SlsPerDts
.Where(d => d.BegDt > Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2014"))
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Yr, x.PerNum })
.Select(p => p.OrderBy(j => j.BegDt).FirstOrDefault())
.ToList()
.Dump();
```

And here is the C# code that doesn't work in my program:

```
var result = db.SLSPERDTs
 .Where(d => d.BEGDT > Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2014"))
 .GroupBy(x => new { x.YR, x.PERNUM })
 .Select(p => p.OrderBy(j => j.BEGDT).FirstOrDefault());

var newresult = result.ToList();
```

It compiles w/o any errors, but the ToList() method makes it blow up every time.  As for drivers, I'm running both pieces of code from the same machine (sorry, drivers is not my speciality).  In LINQPad I simply pointed to the same Oracle database that I'm using with the C# code.  In the LINQPad code, changing it to First() or FirstOrDefault() doesn't appear to make any difference, it works in either case!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something else in LINQPad that, of course, works perfectly and gives the same answer as above.

```
SlsPerDts
.Where(d => d.BegDt > Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2014"))
.OrderBy(j => j.BegDt)
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Yr, x.PerNum })
.Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault())
.ToList()
.Dump();
```

Of course, this too blows up in my C# code.  If I code the following in my C# code, it doesn't blow up, but then, it doesn't give me the correct results either.

```
SlsPerDts
.Where(d => d.BegDt > Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2014"))
.OrderBy(j => j.BegDt)
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Yr, x.PerNum })
.FirstOrDefault()
.ToList()
.Dump();
```

Thanks,
Craig